# error executing procedure in the loop

Tags: c#, sql, .net, stored-procedures, ado.net

I'm facing problem while executing procedure inside loop. My requirment is to insert data to table. first column is alphabet which I try to get in loop and next three are common for all rows. But I'm getting error after first iteration saying that variable must be unique.

```
string str = Properties.Settings.Default.con;
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str);

char[] az = Enumerable.Range('A', 'Z' - 'A' + 1).Select(i => (Char)i).ToArray();


SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Execute InsertPurchase  @ShipTo,@StoreName,@desc,@Alpha", con);
try
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ShipTo", txtstoreto.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StoreName", txtstorefrom.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@desc", Globals.s_desc.ToString());
    con.Open();
    foreach (var c in az)
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Alpha", c.ToString());
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    con.Close();
    j = true;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Error message:

> The variable name '@Alpha' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure.

Comment: That's because of your `foreach`. Foreach c in az you add the new parameter. Build your c-string before you add it as a parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're adding parameter `Alpha` in the loop over and over again.

So instead of adding it in the loop you just have to set its value:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Alpha", SqlDbType.VarChar);
con.Open();
foreach (var c in az)
{
    cmd.Parameters["@Alpha"].Value = c.ToString();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Also notice that using of `AddWithValue` is not a good idea in most cases since it tries to deduce parameter type from the value passed. In most cases it is better to explicitly set parameter type.

Comment: In order to your answer being *complete* one, please add a line above with `@Alpha` parameter creation

Comment: I'm getting this error now! 
An SqlParameter with ParameterName '@Alpha' is not contained by this SqlParameterCollection.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------

Comment: @Jobin it is exactly what Dmitry pointed out. See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you keep on adding the @Alpha parameter over and over...
First time add the parameter and set the value.
Every subsequent iteration, just set the value.

eg first iteration....

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Alpha", c.ToString());
```

Subsequent iterations....

```
cmd.Parameters["@Alpha"].Value = c.ToString();
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you can move all parameter declarations in your for loop and [`Clear`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.clear) them in every iteration.

```
foreach (var c in az)
{
    cmd.Parameters.Clear();
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ShipTo", txtstoreto.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StoreName", txtstorefrom.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@desc", Globals.s_desc.ToString());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Alpha", c.ToString());
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

But of course, this adds *unnecessary* first 3 parameter in every iteration and clear them again.

By the way, don't use `AddWithValue` as much as you can. [It *may* generate unexpected and surprising results sometimes](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). Use `Add` method overload to specify your parameter type and it's size.

Also use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your connection and command automatically instead of calling `Close` or `Dispose` methods manually.

Answer (score 0):

You have to clear the variable to add again Something like this:

```
foreach (var c in az)
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Clear();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ShipTo", txtstoreto.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StoreName", txtstorefrom.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@desc", Globals.s_desc.ToString());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Alpha", c.ToString());
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```